# USB serial communication PHP/ARDUINO under Windows 7

Tags: php, serial-port, arduino

I'm working on a project where I need to command an Arduino controller from a coonected PC through the usb port.
I'am using PHP 5.4 and a the class PhpSerial.php from Rémy Sanchez but there some pb with it.
for example: this script works good and sends character '3' to arduino but if i change 3 to 1 it won't work anymore ... 0 works 2 no 4 no 5 yes 9 yes ...

```
<?php
require("PhpSerial.php");
$serial = new phpSerial;
$serial->deviceSet("COM2");
$serial->confParity("none");
$serial->confCharacterLength(8); 
$serial->confStopBits(1);  
$serial->confFlowControl("none");
$serial->confBaudRate(9600);
$serial->deviceOpen();
$serial->sendMessage("3");
$serial->deviceClose();
?>
```

I tried echo "3" > COM2 and it works and powershell also works good
Can I fix that pb?
can I just use exec to launch commands?
thank you!

update:
I discovered a strange thing : if i send '2' with ascii code 00110010 i receive 10110010 with the last bit altered!!!

Comment: What do you mean by " it won't work anymore "? Does it throw errors?

Comment: i use the received code to blink the led so when i send 3 its blinks 3 times but if ùi send 1 or 2 or 4 nothing happens ... it doesn't show any error

Comment: Are there any errors in the error log?

Comment: there is no error ... read/write operation succeed however i discovered a strange thing : if i send '2' with ascii code 00110010 i receive 10110010 with the last bit altered!!!

Comment: I do not know this PHP library, but don't you need to configure a start bit? Also, is the Arduino board set to 9600 baud?

Comment: Yes arduino is set to the same rate : Serial.begin(9600); now regarding a start bit that lib has no interface to configure such parameter

Answer (score -1):

```
 @echo off
rem mode com10 Baud=9600 PARITY=n Data=8 Stop=1 dtr=off rts=off

rem timeout 1
rem If [%1]==[] 
mode com7 Baud=1200 PARITY=n Data=8 Stop=1 dtr=off rts=off>null

rem echo test>//./com10
rem set /p x='%1' <nul >\\.\COM10
rem set /p x=%1 <nul >\\.\COM10
rem set /p x= <nul >\\.\COM10
echo %1>//./com7
rem echo %1>//./com10
rem timeout 5
exit
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers as these are considered to be of low quality. Add some explanation to your answer.